# SQL issue using sqlzoo database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have an assignment to select all the directors names that directed the Robert De Niro movies,movie titles and year using the [sqlzoo.net](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations) "more join" database. I managed to select the movie titles, and all the director ID from the db. 
The problem is that I don't know how to link the ID to the name...
If u take the code I post,u will see the result in the right side of the page.I need help with it,so that it shows director NAMES instead of IDs.
Note that movie.director key matches the actor.name one ! Need to connect them somehow.

I used this code :

```
select distinct movie.director,movie.title,yr
from movie join casting 
on movie.id=movieid join actor on actor.id=actorid
where movie.id in(select movie.id 
                  from movie join casting on movie.id=movieid 
                  join actor on actor.id=actorid 
                  where actor.name='Robert De Niro')
                  order by yr DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it, you just need to change the criteria for the join to `actor` in the outer query to use `movie.director`, and select `actor.name` instead of `movie.director`:

```
select distinct actor.name,movie.title,yr
from movie 
join casting on movie.id = movieid 
join actor on actor.id = movie.director
where movie.id in(select movie.id 
                  from movie join casting on movie.id=movieid 
                  join actor on actor.id = actorid 
                  where actor.name='Robert De Niro')
order by yr DESC
```

Since the actor table has both actors and directors, using a table alias may make it easier to read:

```
select distinct director.name,movie.title,yr
from movie 
join casting on movie.id = movieid 
join actor AS director on director.id = movie.director
where movie.id in(select movie.id 
                  from movie join casting on movie.id=movieid 
                  join actor on actor.id = actorid 
                  where actor.name='Robert De Niro')
order by yr DESC
```

Comment: Yea :) That makes total sense ! Thanks alot !

Comment: Yep,understood what u did the first time :) Thank you again :D

Comment: FYI - There is no reason for the sub-select in your where clause.  You could do it through simple joins.

Answer (score 0):

This how it would look assuming there is a `director` table and the `movie.director` field matches the `director.id` field.

```
select director.name, movie.title, yr 
from   movie 
       join casting on movie.id = casting.movieid 
       join actor on actor.id = movie.actorid 
       join actor as director on director.id = movie.director 
where actor.name='Robert De Niro'
order by yr DESC
```

Comment: Yes,but I need to use these tables as they are. And movie.director key matches the actor.id one, and somehow I need to connect them.

Comment: Add to the question the structure of your tables and their relationships and it will make it easier for us to answer your question.

Comment: Yea,sorry,I am new here. Edited the relationship after you posted :(